# How can I use signalr in server broadcast to a single client only, not all clients?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I want to create a dashboard using signalr server broadcasting to a single client only, not all clients.

Comment: Are you on ASP.NET Core or .NET Framework? In general you can use Groups for that. Your client connects to a group (passing maybe some params) and before adding to the group, you can apply some logic to ensure only one is added (or that the client is allowed on the group). Then when broadcasting messages, you send to that group.

Comment: This documentation should help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections

Comment: From inside the Hub you can do `Clients.Others.SendAsync(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you create group for each user
(user use multitab in browser and call back new connectionid)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-5.0
and

```
    public class MyEndPoint : PersistentConnection 
{
    protected override IList<string> OnRejoiningGroups(IRequest request, IList<string> groups, string connectionId)
    {
        return groups;
    }
}
```